# definition of 'sigma^2' in the output of summary(ARMA(..)) command in R

Tags: r, time-series

In R, using the [tseries](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tseries/tseries.pdf) package, the summary(arma(..)) command produces an output that contains 'sigma^2' value. What, exactly, is this number means?

here is the documentation:

> The summary method computes the asymptotic standard errors of the
>   coefficient estimates from the numerically differentiated Hessian
>   matrix approximation. The AIC is computed from the conditional
>   sum-of-squared errors and not from the true maximum likelihood
>   function. That may be problematic.

It does not say anythign about 'sigma^2'.

Answer (score 1):

If you write the ARMA model as:
y[t] =a[0] +a[1]y[t−1] +. . .+a[p]y[t−p] +b[1]e[t−1] +. . .+b[q]e[t−q] + e[t]

then $\sigma^2$ should be the variance of e[t].